# Ruby on Rails 3 - callbacks not working any more

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, callback

---

Hi people.

I have a big problem. Untill 2 weeks ago, my code was working fine, but today I realize that some callbacks are not working any more.

The callback is the following:

```
class DetailPurchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :purchase, :foreign_key => 'purchase_id'
  belongs_to :product, :foreign_key => 'product_id'
  belongs_to :buy_order_detail, :foreign_key => 'buy_detail_id'

  def before_create
    Storage.create!(:product_id => self.product_id, :current_quantity => self.quantity, :stg_data => purchase.prc_data)
  end

end
```

The idea is that everytime a Detail_purhase is created, a storage with the same product should be created automatically after that.

But now it is not working, the only change is now I'm using jquery instead of prototype

Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird it worked. Correct syntax is:

```
class DetailPurchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :purchase, :foreign_key => 'purchase_id'
  belongs_to :product, :foreign_key => 'product_id'
  belongs_to :buy_order_detail, :foreign_key => 'buy_detail_id'
  before_create :create_storage 

  def create_storage
    Storage.create!(:product_id => self.product_id, :current_quantity => self.quantity, :stg_data => purchase.prc_data)
  end
end
```

Comment: I already tried that and didn't work for me. I posted just a portion of the code, I have other callbacks and validations, maybe the problem occurs due to some incompatibilities between that callback and the validations??

Comment: I tried a debug and as a result I got that callback was nil... I don't understand.